# Pandas 0.17.1 error subtracting datetime64[ns] cols if dataframe is empty

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I just updated from pandas 0.16.2 to 0.17.1 and am now getting this error when executing existing code that worked fine in 0.16.2

```
TypeError: ufunc substract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

I'm trying to subtract two datetime64 cols on a subset of a dataframe given certain criteria. The error only seems to happen when the subset is empty. In 0.16.2 the below sample code returns a new column D with NaN values, but in 0.17.1 I get the above error.

Any ideas? I need to get this code working again and was hoping not to downgrade back to 0.16.2

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B': ['2016-02-11 05:15:34', '2016-02-11 04:04:54'], 'C': ['2016-02-11 14:08:02', '2016-02-12 01:58:51']})
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
ix = df['A']==3
df.loc[ix, 'D'] = (df[ix]['C'] - df[ix]['B']) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

df returned in 0.16.2:

```
   A                   B                   C   D
0  1 2016-02-11 05:15:34 2016-02-11 14:08:02 NaN
1  2 2016-02-11 04:04:54 2016-02-12 01:58:51 NaN
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? if your last line is this :`df.loc[ix, 'D'] = (df['C'] - df['B']) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')` then it works fine in `0.17.1`

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're trying to do here, you're generating a mask that will select no rows, you then try some kind of chained indexing using this mask which even if this was a valid operation would select no rows anyway

Comment: In this example `ix` is a simplified boolean vector that is suppose to select no rows to simulate the error I'm getting, but your first comment seems to fix my issue. Looks like I was using loc incorrectly. The conditional statement that I'm using is much more complex and in cases where no rows are returned the column that I'm trying to calculate should be null. This method worked fine in 0.16.2